# get specific string pattern

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I have the following string :

```
string str ="dasdsa|cxzc|12|#dsad#|czxc";
```

I need a function that return : `#dsad#`

Taking under consideration that `#dsad#` is created dynamically so it may vary and it's length may vary also

How can i do that using regular expression (searching for the string between the two hashtags) or other method if available ?

Comment: "Taking under consideration that #dsad# is created dynamically so it may vary and it's length may vary also " Can you clarify what `#dsad#` is then if can vary?

Comment: it is a database value and str is a string used in a cookie

Comment: Is it a pipe-delimited string? Split with `|`, and grab the value that starts and ends with `#`. See http://ideone.com/yk34S3

Comment: it is a database value and str is a string used in a cookie

Comment: It's not really relevant that its a DB-stored, cookie item or whatever. You need to be clearer on the format. What is the format (eg, does it always start and end in `#`'s? is it the only item in the list that follows that format? What is the dynamic element of it? What information are you trying to extract?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your string is a pipe-delimited string, you may split with `|`, and grab the value that starts and ends with `#`.

```
var str ="dasdsa|cxzc|12|#dsad#|czxc";
var result = str.Split('|').Where(p => p.StartsWith("#") && p.EndsWith("#")).ToList();
foreach (var s in result)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

See [the online C# demo](http://ideone.com/yk34S3).

If you only need one value, use `.FirstOrDefault()`:

```
var result = str.Split('|')
   .Where(p => p.StartsWith("#") && p.EndsWith("#"))
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Personally, [I prefer .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wRbLqC) over Ideone. It feels much more intuitive and faster.

Comment: @UweKeim: Yes, it is also great. I prefer to be on the [de gustibus non est disputandum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_gustibus_non_est_disputandum) side.

Comment: Looks like it is a downvoting day today. +1 to everyone who answered.

Comment: To me, it is upvote Wiktor Stribiżew day! Sorry that you get downvotes without a comment.

Comment: @UweKeim: Thank you for a positive attitude. :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for this gesture, I already spent my +1 for you in the beginning. Nice condition with `StartsWith` and `EndsWith`!

Comment: I upvoted one of the newbies answers with my +1; the new people need a welcome note when attempting...not a slap in the face when to trying to provide an answer to a question.  I had written a meta question about answering SO Regex questions, for I feel there is a general bias: [Bias against Regular Expression Questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118429/bias-against-regular-expression-questions) back in 2012

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I down-voted every answer. The reason being that the question is poor and very unclear and all the answers were guesses. It's only because this answer was accepted can we work back to what was really being asked for.

Comment: @DavidArno: You do not like the question, downvote the question. Period.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I disagree. It's as important to down vote guessing answers as the poor question.

Comment: @DavidArno So you downvoted legitimate, dare I say valid answers, because **you** didn't understand the question. Nice.....

Comment: @DavidArno: For me and a lot of others, the question was crystal clear. The leading/trailing `#`s formed a pattern, *anything* could be between them, *searching for the string between the two hashtags* confirms that (the user meant *hashes*, OP - from Lebanon! - just might not know English well, typos and bad English happen often.) Let's avoid this long conversation here in the comments, since I doubt we can make one another change our beliefs. Time will judge.

Comment: @OmegaMan Don't be silly. Answers starting with "if" and "assuming" are clearly guesses due to the question being unclear. The question adds nothing to SO as a knowledge repository and the answers are random "if you mean x, then y" and so aren't of any use to anyone but the question-asker.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to match on the # character you can take the following regex:

`#[a-z]+#`

- "[]" character set
- "+" one character or more

If you want your string is always of the form 1|2|3|#4#|5 you could use the String.Split('|') method and just take the fourth element of the result.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `#dasd#` appears only once in the string try this:

```
String a = "asd|asd|#this#|asdasd";


string m = Regex.Match(a, @"#.+#").Value;

Console.WriteLine(m);
```

`.+` searches for any character

IF your string is using the `|` as delimiter, you could also split the string.

```
string [] array = a.Split('|');

// this would get a list off all values with `#`
List<string> found_all = array.Where(x => x.Contains("#")).ToList();

// this would get the first occurrence of that string. If not found it will return null
string found = array.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains("#"))
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the input given in the Question that you need to search for the string between the two hashtags following will be the regex,

```
^.*#(.*)#.*$
```

If the data is empty between 2 hashtags, still the regex will not fail. It will take empty value.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be CSV delimited data with five sections of data.

Extract each of the sections and then project into a dynamic entity using regex to denote each of the sections.

```
string data = "dasdsa|cxzc|12|#dsad#|czxc";

string pattern = @"(?<Section1>[^|]+)\|(?<Section2>[^|]+)\|(?<Section3>[^|]+)\|(?<Section4>[^|]+)\|(?<Section5>[^|]+)";

var results =
Regex.Matches(data, pattern, RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture)
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select(mt => new
     {
            One = mt.Groups["Section1"].Value,
            Two = mt.Groups["Section2"].Value,
            Three = mt.Groups["Section3"].Value,
            Four = mt.Groups["Section4"].Value,
            Five = mt.Groups["Section5"].Value,
     })
     .ToList();

    Console.WriteLine(results[0].Four ); // #dsad#
```

Once complete extract from what `results` contains. For it is just a list of the multi-line captures, where each line contains just is one entity of data for that line.

Extract from the appropriate properties; whereas our final result on has one line, but we can get to the data as shown in the example `WriteLine`:

[image]